# Does 'overcharging' a sniper increase its damage?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-sniper

As a Sniper, I know that if I charge my sniper rifle, it will do more damage, but does the time for which it is 'overcharged' (i.e. scoped in when the charge meter is already full) affect the damage it does on its next shot?

The reason I ask is that, a couple of times, I have scoped in for about 30 seconds (in a sneaky spot) and have dealt about 500-600 damage (which is more than enough to kill even a fully-overhealed Heavy). Is this just a coincidence?

If 'overcharging' a sniper **does** increase its damage, is there an upper limit to how much damage it can do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

Once the meter is full, the sniper rifle will deal maximum damage (normally 150 for bodyshots, 450 for headshots). Charging longer than this won't increase the damage any further.

You probably dealt 500 damage because of the Machina's +15% damage on fully charged shots. This would give you 518 damage (though 450 also kills a fully overhealed heavy).

Comment: It's also possible the Heavy was wearing an item with a debuff, like the GORU.  Though that would've indicated a Mini-Crit, which is overridden by a crit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

On [this page](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Machina), you can read about the sniper Machina, which is a sniper that deals 15% extra damage when fully charged.

"*A fully charged shot fired by the Machina delivers an extra 15% damage, can pierce through multiple enemies, and has a distinct firing sound.*"

This is the only sniper that gets bonus damage for being fully charged.

Comment: All rifles do more damage when charged...